# What runes are used with Shen for Tanking?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently started playing Shen and I seem to be pretty decent with him.

I know everything is situation based but I am looking for a good set of Tanking runes and a good early game item set.

So far for I have 9 marks for HP, 9 seals for armour, 9 Glyphs for magic resist as my runes. I am wondering what Quiescence's to buy to fit with this set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a guide](http://www.lolpro.com/guides/shen/146-shen-guide-top-lane) created by a pro player for Shen on top lane runes, masteries, and items.

> 3x Movement Speed Quints:  I like to move fast to harass enemies in lane and one of the biggest things with these is once you teleport in onto an allie you're going to want to taunt someone most likely or chase down someone who's low. What better way to do that then to have increased movement speed! They're perfect for initiating and escaping too!

OR

> 3x Flat AP Quints: Personally I prefer the MS quints for overall game utility but if you really want to dominate the lane then having this early will surely help you do that. The added bit of sustain and DPS makes him that much stronger in lane.

It's really up to you on what quints you like using. Both are viable.

Comment: When answering make sure to quote the link rather than just posting it so if the source of the guide is removed the answer is still here

Comment: Thank you for the tip kind sir I will make sure to remember that in the future :P

Comment: Blem did not mean "put the link in quotes"  He meant put the content of the link in a quote block.  You can highlight a chunk of text and click the `"` on the toolbar to make a quote block or simply place a `>` at the beginning of the paragraph you want to quote.

Comment: I hope this is what you meant i shall remember to use this in the future

Comment: Much better.  I added the link to the guide back in so people could see your source and get additional info.  Welcome to the site!